# Ошибка "E0077 это объявление не содержит класс хранения или спецификатор типа"

Tags: c++, авторизация, аутентификация

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>

void register_1();
void read(std::string login, std::string password);
void login();

struct Users {
    std::string login;
    std::string password;
}users[100];
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    std::cout << "1. Пройти регистрацию \n";
    std::cout << "2. Выполнить вход в систему \n";
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    switch (a) {
    case 1: register_1();
    case 2: login();
    }
    return 0;
}

void register_1() {
    std::string login, password;
    std::cout << "Введите логин:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> login;
    std::cout << "Введите пароль:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> password;
    std::ofstream fout("users.txt", std::ios::app);
    fout << login << " " << password << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Регистрация прошла успешно!" << std::endl;
    main();
}

void read(std::string login, std::string password) {
    std::ifstream fin("users.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        fin >> users[i].login >> users[i].password;
    }

}
void login() {
    std::string login, password;
    std::cout << "Введите логин:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> login;
    std::cout << "Введите пароль:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> password;
    read(login, password);
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (login == users[i].login && password == users[i].password) {
            std::cout << "Вы успешно вошли!" << std::endl;
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == true) {
        std::cout << "Пароль либо логин введены неверно!" << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    main();
}
```

при компиляции выдаёт такие ошибки:
Ошибка (активно)    E0077   это объявление не содержит класс хранения или спецификатор типа ConsoleApplication1 f:\cours1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp   66
и
Ошибка  C1004   непредвиденное обнаружение конца файла  ConsoleApplication1 f:\cours1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp   67

не могу понять от куда эти ошибки, 66 строка выглядит так - `}` (самая последняя закрывающая скобка), а 67 вообще отсутствует, даже пробела там нет.

Comment: Почему у тебя в конце есть main(); ?
Он сам вызывается.

Answer (score 1):

У вас после последней скобки, похоже, затесался указатель кодировки UTF-8 - EF BB BF. Только и всего. Проверьте сами - он даже у вас здесь, в вашем коде наличествует...

Но мне ужасно интересно другое - что за вызов `main()` в `login()` - что бы это значило?

Comment: main в login для возврата к выбору после неправильного ввода данных, но это я буду убирать. Как проверить наличие этого указателя? не могу найти...

Comment: С указателем разобрался, он был невидим, просто нажал "очистить". А вот "непредвиденное  обнаружение конца файла" так и осталось на 67 строке

Comment: Попробуйте добавить лишний перевод строки после последней фигурной скобки.